# How to set Sqlite PRAGMA options (ie. "primary_key = On") programatically?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a C++ program that connects to Sqlite3 using the following command line:

```
int ret = sqlite3_open("databasefilename", &dbHandler);
```

After opening the database, I need to enable PRIMARY_KEYS, like I would do using plain SQL:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Is there a C++ single command that will allow me to do it ? I know on PHP we can use:

```
        $service = new \Sqlite3($filename);
        $service->enforceForeignKeys(true);
```

Something similar in C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the C/C++ API for SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3), the foreign-key constraints enforcement option is specified in your call to `sqlite3_db_config()`:

```
sqlite3* db;
int err = sqlite3_open( "databaseFileName", &db );
if( err != SQLITE_OK ) /* die */

int fkeyConstraintsEnabled;
err = sqlite3_db_config( db, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_FKEY, /* either 0 or 1 to disable/enable constraints */, &fkeyConstraintsEnabled );
if( err != SQLITE_OK ) /* die */

printf( "Constraints now enabled: %d\r\n", fkeyConstraintsEnabled );
```

Conceivably you could write a function to wrap this in C/C++:

```
void enforceForeignKeys( sqlite3* db, bool enforceForeignKeyConstraints ) {

    int expectedNewValue = enforceForeignKeyConstraints ? 1 : 0;
    int actualNewValue;

    int err = sqlite3_db_config( db, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_FKEY, expectedNewValue, &actualNewValue);
    if( err != SQLITE_OK ) throw err;
    if( actualNewValue != expectedNewValue ) throw SOME_USER_DEFINED_ERROR;
}
```